# MATLAB isequal function gives wrong answer for symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In the following simple code:

```
syms x
isequal((x+1)^2, x^2+2*x+1)
```

MATLAB returns false, but two expressions are same!
What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not exactly the same expressions, and `isequal()` tests for expression equality. Try for example:

```
>> isequal(expand((x+1)^2), x^2+2*x+1)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

or,

```
>> isequal(simplify((x+1)^2), simplify(x^2+2*x+1))

ans =

  logical

   1
```

PS you could also use `isAlways()` to compare expressions,

```
isAlways((x+1)^2 == x^2+2*x+1)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Comment: Thanks. Then what I should use is the isAlways function.